# How to setup template base path for Jersey in Grizzly http server?

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

With *Apache Jersey* and *Grizzly http server*, how do I setup base template path ?

Since I'm not using Servlet container, I assign template base path with absolute file path. But Jersey response a 404.

Following is my project setup

**Project Directory** :

```
src
 └─ java
      .....
 └─ resources
    └─ templates
       └─ index.mustache
```

**Application** :

```
public class ExampleApplication extends ResourceConfig {

  public CustomTableApplication() {
    packages("com.example.app");

    setupTemplateEngine();
  }

  private void setupTemplateEngine() {
    property(MvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "/templates/");
    register(MustacheMvcFeature.class);
  }
}
```

**Controller** :

```
@Path("/")
public class Index {

  @GET
  @Template(name = "index")
  public String index() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

**How I create HttpServer** :

```
HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("example", "localhost", 8080);
server.addListener(listener);

ServerConfiguration config = server.getServerConfiguration();
config.addHttpHandler(createJerseyHandler(), "/*");
```

Comment: Pls. try to register HttpHandler like: config.addHttpHandler(createJerseyHandler(), "/*");

Comment: What does createJerseyHandler() return, exactly? Is there a HTTPHandler for Mustache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I misunderstood how Jersey find template file when resolving template name.

With resource `com.example.app.Index` and template base path `/templates`

**Relative Template Reference**  `@Template(name = "index")`

`/templates/com/example/app/Index/index.mustache`

**Absolute Template Reference**  `@Template(name = "/index")`

`/templates/index.mustache`

see document for more detail
 : [19.3. Absolute vs. Relative template reference](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.7/user-guide.html#mvc.references)